# Angular 12+ работа с формой

Tags: angular

Есть много полей формы и кнопка сабмит , они все не обязательны , кнопка изначально disabled , но как только в одном из полей что то заполнили , раздизейблить , а если стереть , опять дизейбл , пробовал с !form.dirty , работает , но если стер данные с поля , кнопка остается активной

Answer (score 0):

В шаблоне на кнопку

```
[disabled]="isDisabled"
```

В компоненте

```
get isDisabled(): boolean {
  for (const control of this.form.controls) {
    if (control.value) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return  true;
}
```